# TreeMap in R giving error for some values of hmax

Tags: r, lidar, las

I am using the TreeLs library's treetop function. My code is as follows:

```
map = treeMap(tls, map.hough(hmin = 4, hmax = 6, hstep = 0.5, min_density = 0.01, max_radius = 0.4, pixel_size = 0.10))
```

It's giving me an error for some values of hmax:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, 1:.N, `:=`(X = round_any(X, factor), Y = round_any(Y,  :

 i[1] is 1 which is out of range [1,nrow=0]
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the function does and at which step this problem arises. It is when returning an output or more at the beginning of the function? Only the developer of `treeLS` can know. But the problem is that, somewhere in the code, a `data.table` object with 0 row has been edited with a non 0 length `i`.

```r
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = numeric(), n = integer())
dt[1:.N, a := a + 1]
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, 1:.N, `:=`(a, a + 1)) : 
#>  i[1] is 1 which is out of range [1,nrow=0]
```

This should be reported as a bug to the maintainer.